# Is it possible to extra/interpolate probabilities?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Is it possible to extra/interpolate probabilities ?

Lets say: $\qquad$ $P(X\geq3)=y\qquad$ and $\qquad P(X\leq5)=z$ $\qquad$($y,z$ are already known)

Can I calculate $P(X=4)$ and $P(X=6)$?

Bonus question:

Is it possible to calculate $F(i)=P(X\leq i)$ faster than adding $f(i)+f(i-1)+...+f(0)$?

Comment: I've edited your question - this site uses [MathJax for typesetting of formulas](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). This makes your questions more readable and therefore more likely to be answered.

Comment: I don't know why the answer below is saying you can't. Of course you can. If you have a distribution that looks normal and has the left side missing (IE. truncated normal)... and you might even have a reason to believe the left side is missing due to some error... you will need to extrapolate. In fact, even MLH estimator would also interpolate/extrapolate the distribution from fixed data, just draw some data from the distribution and estimate the parameters for the new distribution. You will have to make some assumptions, however.

Comment: As for the bonus question, yes it's possible. You can also start from the other side of the distribution, or multiply constants etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

---

In special cases, if your probabilities $y$ and $z$ are equal to $0$ or $1$, it is possible to infer some facts.

For example, if we know that $P(X\geq 3) = 0$ then we know that $P(X =4) = 0$ and $P(X = 6)= 0$.

Or, if you know that $P(X \leq 5) = 1$ then we know that $P(X = 6) = 0$.

Or, if you know that $P(X \leq 5) = 0$ then we know that $P(X = 4) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for editing my question. In my practice Problems I have one like this: In 10 minutes there is a probability of 0.8 that at least 3 people are passing by, the probability that 5 people at most are passing by is 0.4. I need to find the probability of 3,4 and 6 people passing by. How could I go on to solve something like this? Did I look at it wrong and its done via possion-distribution?

Comment: @JDizzle In that practice question, what are you asked to find?

Comment: Oops forgot that, it's the probability of 3, 4 and 6 people passing by.

Comment: @JDizzle Do you know anything else about the number of people passing by? Is there a maximum? Is it given by a random variable with a distribution that you know (e.g. Poisson, exponential, whatever)?

Comment: Everything i got from the question is: time window (10min) and the two probabilities: 0.8 for at least 3 people, 0.4 for at most 5.

Comment: @JDizzle Well that is not enough information to solve it - are you sure you don't know anything else?

Comment: Well the 10minutes are observed between 10:00 and 12:00. Here is my shot at translating the question. While investigating a local street we found that between 10:00 and 12:00 every 10minutes at least 3 people are passing by with a probability of 0.8 and with a probability of 0.4 at most 5 people are passing. How high is the probability that in 10minutes 3,4,5,6 people are passing.

Comment: With things like the number of cars passing by a road, or people walking by, often a [Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) distribution is assumed - if you can assume that the number of people passing by is a Poisson random variable $X \sim \text{Pois}(\lambda)$ then you can use the two facts given to find the value of $\lambda$, which will then allow you to find the probabilities $P(X = 3), P(X=4)$, etc.

Comment: Then I can calculate $E(X)=\sum_{i=1}^r x_i*P(x_i)$ with $\frac{3}{2}*0.8 = x_i, $$\frac{5}{2}*0.4 = x_2 $ right? The outcome would be lambda.

Answer (score 0):

OP states in one of the comments:

> In my practice Problems I have one like this: In 10 minutes there is a probability of 0.8 that at least 3 people are passing by, the probability that 5 people at most are passing by is 0.4. I need to find the probability of 3,4 and 6 people passing by.

I am thinking there is likely a typo in the last part. That is, the textbook author might have meant the setup as this (converted symbolically): Given $P(X\geq 3)=0.8$ and $P(X\leq 5)=0.4$, find $P(3 \leq X \leq 5)$.

Making the leap that this is the intended question (considering an introductory probability question), then this becomes rather elementary:

\begin{align}
P(3 \leq X \leq 5) &= P(X \leq 5)-P(X \leq 2)\\
&= P(X \leq 5)-\left\{1-P(X \geq 3)\right\}\\
&= 0.4 - \left\{1-0.8\right\} = 0.4-0.2=0.2
\end{align}